# Next Js + Amplify @sls-next/-component error on deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify, serverless

I've deployed my app on amplify, the backend deployment is all good to go.

I've connected the frontend to my gitlab repo, and after debugging it is finally compiled successfully. Immediately after the compiling, I get this error.

```
Starting SSR Build...
[ERROR]: Error: Command failed: npm install @sls-next/-component@3.7.0 --prefix /root/./
```

I have tried to override the env with the following commands (I've tried previous versions of both next and node, however it doesnt pass the compiling phase unless I use the following)

```
Amplify CLI - latest
Next.js version - latest
Node.js version - 17
```

This is my amplify.yml

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

My node_module versions on the project are

```
 "next": "^12.1.7-canary.16",
 "react": "^18.0.0",
 "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
 "aws-amplify": "^4.3.23"
```

my node version is 17.0.9 and my local amplify cli is 8.2.0

I should note my build passes locally

What am I missing? I dont have serverless installed anywhere on my project, it appears to be something amplify is trying to install. Perhaps I should be exporting after the build? But this is an ssr app, not static. I have a feeling this is a problem with conflicting versions.

,

Comment: This *just* started happening to me and I'd love to know what caused it - nothing obvious to me. Could it be a problem with amplify?

Comment: @ColinRiddell What Next.js version are you on? Does dowgrading to a previous version help? I suspect it could've been an issue introduced in some canary release that led to 12.2.0 release.

Comment: @juliomalves - I'm using 12.1.0 .I wasn't aware. I'll look into this and update the post accordingly if it is that.

Comment: AWS amplify is pure nonsense. Probably some college students' project it is. Highly unreliable.